# Run queries execution in Jinja template

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, flask, jinja2

### How can get `db.execute("SELECT * FROM table ...")` in this html?

[image]

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db_admin = SQL("sqlite:///administration.db")
@app.route("/settings", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def setting():
    if request.method == "POST":

        return render_template("settings.html")
```

I have a database and need in my template (settings.html) `UPDATE table SET ...` value in database when`onchange` event happens in `td`.

```
<td onclick="query();">{{ cell }}</td>
```

I have try:

```
function query()
{
    let sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./administration.db');
    row= db.execute("UPDATE table SET user_group=? WHERE ...", value);
}
```

Please assume the value is inpute text value.

---

Comment: HTML code is read only, you cannot make calls to database using it. Your code appears to be JavaScript code, but you cannot install sqlite3 dependencies on JavaScript that is running on a browser. Instead, you should run the code that calls the database in your Flask code, check SQLAlchemy that simplifies the process of calling a database: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-flask-sqlalchemy-to-interact-with-databases-in-a-flask-application

Comment: You should think about what is processed on the server and what is processed on the client and what certain techniques are suitable for in which environment. Not everything can be combined in every way.

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka
@Detlef
I want code in flask serverside, When execute `render_templates("setting.html")` the desired value `UPDATE table SET ...` have done.

Comment: May I right serverside sqlite query execution code by flask in template html?

Comment: It is true that you should run your database operations within an endpoint/route on the server. The template is not suitable for this. To send your data from the client/browser to the server, the simplest solution is a form. So you transfer your data to the template and display it in a form. After sending this to the server using the POST method, you can update a database entry within the endpoint. Eduardo gave you a hint on how to integrate databases into an application using an ORM. However, you can also manage your database manually.

Comment: @Detlef, I know database manipulation in the route. So the desired textboxes are shown above are implemented in a form. But what I need is when user have type a character, suddenly made database `UPDATE...`, (`onchange` event) But the form action and query execution in endpoint is slow. And may dangerous in data loss. (Seems user has edited many text boxes and forgot press submit button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is getting a lot of traffic. I think it makes more sense to point out to the user that they left unsaved data. You could use a `beforeunload` event for this. However, this hits a limit when the user closes the window.
The code could look something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            let isChanged = false;
            document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(elem => {
                elem.addEventListener('change', () => {
                    isChanged = true; 
                });
            });

            document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', () => {
                isChanged = false;
            })

            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (evt) => {
                if (isChanged) {
                    evt.returnValue = isChanged;
                }
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

It is still possible, as you have thought, to use AJAX to send the form data to the server in the background for each fired event.

```py
@app.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def settings():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form)
        # Update your database here.
    return render_template('settings.html', **locals())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Call the function when available.
        (function() {
            // Wait for the document to load completely.
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                // Search for all input fields and iterate over them.
                document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(elem => {
                    // Register an EventListener for 'change' events for each input field.
                    elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
                        // Send the entire form to the server as soon as an event is fired.
                        fetch('/settings', {
                            method: 'post', 
                            body: new FormData(this.form)
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you only want to send the changed input and not the whole form, the code is easy to modify.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function() {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(elem => {
                elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append(this.name, this.value); 
                    fetch('/settings', {
                        method: 'post', 
                        body: formData
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    })();

</script>
```

Comment: How function() triggered call? I can't use.

Comment: I want only each typed character get traffic unless sending form entirely. As you mentioned AJAX, how is it? If seems good, do UPDATE... database in case of each character changes.

Comment: @parmer_110 I do not understand your question. The JavaScript function will be executed automatically as soon as the file has been loaded. The first EventListener additionally ensures this. With each `change` event, an AJAX request containing the current form data is sent to the server using the Fetch API. You only need to update the database within your route with `UPDATE ... SET ...`.

Comment: I got, thanks. Then How can send **Only the changed** `input` value to server with AJAX request?

Comment: (I think this reduces the traffic, against sending the entire forum data)

Comment: @parmer_110 I've expanded the answer on this and hope you can relate to it.

Comment: The code for sending changes is pretty good, unless when pressing enter in the text input, will sending all of form data.  But in case of only type, it sends only current ImmutableMultiDict. Is it possible do this, while user have pressed enter. Because all changes are updating simultaneously typing in form.

Comment: When enter is pressed, the form's "submit" event is fired by the button. If you remove the button, this event cannot be fired, but you also no longer have the option of submitting the form in its entirety.

Comment: I have removed the button, but still submitting form entirely when pressing Enter key in the input text.

Comment: Can't say anything, it works for me. The workaround is to register a listener for a form's "submit" event, which just calls [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: The `print(request.form)` prints `ImmutableMultiDict([('edt_8', 'enterprise_adminabv')])` value as example. Is it available get `name` or `value` more direct?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You can use the `ImmutableMultiDict` like a `dict`. The name attribute of the input field is the key with which you can get the value. But you can also iterate over the items with a for loop.